# Restricting Field Access by Role

Tags: 7, entities, users

I'm working on a site in which I'd like anon users to be able to create nodes of a certain type, but I only want them to be able to see/edit some of the fields on that content type.

I can't go into details just yet, but the goal of the site is to crowd-source the collection of information and then have a few administrators who will approve and groom the data. That's why I want anon users to be able to create nodes and only access a few fields. Then admins will be able to supplement that data by adding values into the other fields and then publish that node.

How do I restrict access to fields basing on the roles the users have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions/) module, it does exactly that:

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

It gives you granular access control based on role for every field, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: Any way to control access to the Title? I know it's not a "Field", but I want to generate the Content Title based on other fields. This may be a larger question that I'll need to post separately. Perhaps I'll need to create a module that will intercept the content creation and override the title or something.

Comment: If you want to generate the node title automatically [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle/) is probably the way to go, it has the effect of hiding the title field anyway so would probably suit your needs perfectly

Comment: Where are this features? On the field settings? I can't find it anywhere